# How to debug Azure Function triggered by Service Bus that uses Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I have an azure Function triggered by Service Bus.

```
    [FunctionName("Func")]
    public async Task Run(

        [ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusQueueName%", Connection = "SBNamespaceFQName")]

        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,

        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,

        Int32 deliveryCount,

        DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,

        DateTime expiresAtUtc,

        ILogger log)
    {
        ......
    }
```

The authentication to service bus is done by Managed Identity and for local debug I am using Service Principal by adding the following to Startup

```
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID", "***");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", "***");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", "***");
```

My question is if it is possible to use my Azure User credentials for local debug instead ot Service Principal, assuming my user will get all necessary roles.

For some reason once function is failing to start once I remove from Startup the abovementioned lines even if I am logged in to Azure from Visual Studio.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you can configure your account through `tools -> options -> azure service authentication` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried the option you suggested but for some reason it is not working for me. That's why I am wondering if there is something that I missed

Comment: what is the error message you receive ?

Comment: Error Message: 'Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.

Comment: If using the defaultazurecredentials, it will call that but doesn't mean it wont work, it is just trying to get credentials from different source tho. I will give it a try and see how that goes

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. My user was missing "Azure Service Bus Data Owner" role. Once got this role assigned to my user function started successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***** UPDATE  ******

I was able to figure out what was wrong. My azure user was missing "Azure Service Bus Data Owner" role. After the role was assigned to my uer the issue resolved.